# How should I trigger a UI render update from a state change in a reactjs flux app?

Tags: reactjs, flux

If I'm doing field validation in say a login form field, if it's missing a required field should I trigger the error message in the rendered view by either

a. update this.state.errorMessage in the component and then trigger a render somehow?

OR

b. raise a loginError action, which then updates the store with an errormessage and let that trigger a state update and then the render in the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways will work. It depends on whether you have other components that should also listen to the changes in your `field` validation states:

- **If so**, then you should do the full `flux` cycle by calling the loginError
  `action`, which will update the stores, causing state changes to properly
  propagate to all relevant components that cares about the `field`
  validation states.
- **If not**, where your `field` validation state changes are localized to
  just the current `component`, then it's not wrong to just
  `setState()` within the component and only triggers the `render()` of
  itself.

However I recommend that you will do the full `flux` cycle (action->store->view) since it will be easier to make modifications later.